# Unstaged changes not appearing in magit, plus other oddities

Tags: magit

I'm a Magit rookie and finding it is not behaving as expected. I have multiple unstaged changes in a repository (see "Git Status" below). However, Magit is not showing them (see "Magit" below) when I use `magit-status`. For an additional oddity, the section lising recent commits with hashes and commit messages is not visible in the magit buffer. I only noticed them when I cut and pasted from the buffer in order to make this message.  I'm using the 20191123 of Magit on Emacs 26.3 on MacOS 10.14.6.

Any hints as to where things may not be going right? Thank you.

## Magit

```
Head:     master Refine gitignore
Merge:    origin/master Refine gitignore
Push:     origin/master Refine gitignore

Untracked files (6)
.org-id-locations
annotations
diary


Recent commits
3d97a67 origin/master Refine gitignore
17b56f0 Refine .gitignore
4caad13 Set shell to MacPort's zsh


[33mdiff --git .persistent-scratch .persistent-scratch[m
[33mindex cedd81b..185a428 100644[m
```

## Git status

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  modified:   .persistent-scratch
  modified:   ac-comphist.dat
  modified:   custom.el
  modified:   myinit.org
  modified:   recentf
  modified:   savehist

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
  .org-id-locations
  annotations
  diary

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: That sounds very strange.  Perhaps purge that installation of Magit and instead install the most recent stable release from https://stable.melpa.org/#/magit and see if that behaves differently?

Comment: That "[33mdiff" stuff at the bottom of the magit output looks very suspicious. Have you got a very funky PS1 setting?

Comment: Have you set `color.ui` in your git config? E.g, see https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/733

Answer (score 2):

In line with the suggests above, it was a problem with my Git config.  Commenting the following lines out of my config file resolved the issue.

```
# [color]
#   ui = always
# [color "diff-highlight"]
#   # oldNormal = red bold
#   oldHighlight = red bold 52
#   newNormal = green bold
#   newHighlight = green bold 22
# [color "diff"]
  # commit = green
  # meta = yellow
  # frag = cyan
  # old = red
  # new = green
  # whitespace = red reverse
```

Comment: See https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2603 “`color.ui=true` means "use colors when it makes sense", while `color.ui=always` means "use colors even when it doesn't make any sense" ;-)”

Comment: Also https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Diffs-contain-control-sequences.html